# Progressdialog isshowing returns true even called hide

Tags: android

I have created progress dialog like this

```
public VolleyService(Context context, VolleyServiceCompletedListener listener){
    this.context = context;
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

and tried to show progress dialog using this method.

```
private void showProgressDialog() {
    boolean isShowing = pDialog.isShowing();
    if (!isShowing)
        pDialog.show();
}
```

And hide the dialog using this method.

```
private void hideProgressDialog() {
    if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
        pDialog.hide();
    }
}
```

The problem is `pDialog.isShowing()` returns true even after I have called the `pDialog.hide()`. When I see the `hide()` method from `android.app.Dialog.java` they didn't assign the `mShowing` variable as false, but when I call `show()` they assigned the `mShowing` variable as true.

So is there any reason behind they didn't make as false? And how can I open the same progress dialog again?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

don't use hide() use dismiss() instead. This will also prevent **leaked window error**

refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517739/android-dialog-should-i-hide-or-dimiss) for more info

Answer (score 3):

Please try to dismiss your dialog.

```
pDialog.dismiss()
```